# Using PnP/CSOM to customise New SharePoint OOTB Document Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, provisioning, csom, document-library

Hoping someone could possibly help please.

Quite new to the PnP framework, but I have a template up and running, but I'm drawing a blank on customising the OOTB document library with our own custom content types and site columns. I’ve managed to do it for the initial provisioning process using PnP, but the bit I’m currently struggling with is when a user creates a new document library from either the 'addanapp.aspx' page or through a Modern Page, since that doesn’t use our content types or site columns, that just creates a default SPO Document Library.

I’ve been reading about the ECM Document Library core, List Definitions, Event Receivers and CSOM to achieve what I’m looking to do, but not sure where I should be starting.

Ideally, the outcome I'm looking to achieve is I want any new document library a user creates from a Modern Team Site to use only our custom content types and site columns, not the default OOTB ones.

Any help gratefully received, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the demo [ECM.DocumentLibraries](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/ECM.DocumentLibraries)?

[Here](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/Document-and-list-templates-with-app-model) is the general explanation video.

You need familiar with SharePoint add-in(app) first [guideline here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins).

Comment: Thank you very much for that, will take a look.